# Что такое структуры и модульное программирование?

Tags: c++, книги

Читал Страуструпа, про структуры и модульное программирование, но практически ничего не понял об этом. Прошу объяснить тут, что это такое и где это применяется и дать пару ссылок на хорошие статьи на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл модульного программирования в том, что программу можно писать не одним большим файлом, а разделить на отдельные файлы (модули)... И в этих файлах отдельно программируется интерфейс программы, его отдельные функции и процедуры. а потом при компиляции просто указывается список этих модулей и компилятор их находит и создает исполняемый файл на основе этих файлов. Это упрощает процесс создавание сложных программ и дает возможность создавать программы не одной конторой, а несколькими сразу. Т.е. каждая контора создает свою часть программы, которые потом объединяются...